# How do I save a zip file to a specific location using DotNetZip?

Tags: c#, reference, zip

I'm working on a project that will be zipping directories using the DotNetZip reference. When I use the code:

```
using(ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
{
  try
  {
    zip.AddDirectoryByName(label39.Text);
    zip.Save(@"C:\SecZipped.zip");
  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
    MessageBox.Show("ERROR:\n\n" + ex.Message);
    return;
  }

  MessageBox.Show("Finished.");
}
```

I get the error: Access to the path C:\DotNetZip-04wnaxtt.tmp is denied.

However, when I change @"C:\SecZipped.zip" in the

```
zip.Save(@"C:\SecZipped.zip");
```

to "SecZipped.zip" I get no error but the file is stored where the DotNetZip reference is located.

So can I specify where the zip file is saved?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: `Access to the path C:\DotNetZip-04wnaxtt.tmp is denied.` - is there something unclear about the error message you are getting? It seems like it's already hinting you about what the problem might be - the process you are executing your code under doesn't appear to have sufficient privileges to write to this folder.

Comment: have you tried to specify a folder that you have access to?

Comment: I have and that's when I get the error. I'm secifying the root drive of the C hard drive, and it creates the tmp file on its own.